# Single Table Inheritance - Additional Class Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, single-table-inheritance, sti

I have a situation in my Rails 4 app, where I have STI and want to customize the default queries by additional `type`.

Classes:

```
class Candidate < ApplicationRecord
end

class Candidate::Site < Candidate
end
```

Now, if I make query, I get results as follow:

```
> Candidate::Site.count
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "candidates" WHERE "candidates"."type" IN ('Candidate::Site')
=> 0
```

Now, in my situation, I want to add an additional `type` which query should look for every time. By leveraging the `IN` clause, my expected query to be fired is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "candidates" WHERE "candidates"."type" IN ('Candidate::Site', 'Site')
```

Can someone help me out to control this `IN` clause here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After detailed research and diving deep into the Rails STI source code, I found that my scenario will need to override the Rails' default STI. Following is what I needed to achieve the goal:

```
class Candidate::Site

  # To enable renaming of Site to Candidate::Site
  # per ENG-9551, we need to:
  # 1. disable the 'type' column from using Rails' built-in STI
  self.inheritance_column = :_nonexistant_column_to_bypass_sti

  # 2. manually set the type column to Candidate::Site when we save,
  # so that new and edited records are saved as Candidate::Site
  before_save { self.type = 'Candidate::Site' }

  # 3. always report the type as a Candidate::Site
  def type
    'Candidate::Site'
  end

  # 4. and set a default scope which only reads type columns that are
  # 'Candidate::Site' or 'Site' so that STI
  # still appears to be the same as always
  default_scope { where(type: 'Candidate::Site').or(where(type: 'Site')) }

  ...
  ...
  ...
end
```

So, now any new record created with `Candidate::Site.create` will store type `Candidate::Site` while queries will use default scope and consider both the type, `Candidate::Site` as well as `Site`.

Answer (score 0):

You can query like so:

```
Candidate.where(
  Candidate.inheritance_column => [Candidate::Site, Site, SomeOtherClass].map(&:sti_name)
).count
```

Comment: Actually, I can't do this. The scenario is that I already have my app running with `Candidate::Site` class. Now, I want to rename the class/model to `Site` while I don't want to loose access to my existing table records which have `type=Candidate::Site` without much changes. I want to query existing ones with new class too.

Comment: @RAJ is `Site` just a new name for `Candidate::Site`? If yes - then why not just update records?

Comment: We are doing it in phases. There are many other dependent pieces so we can't do it right away. Thanks